# How to translate words like "the" to other languages?

Tags: translation, articles, morphemes, determiners, definiteness

So this question boils down to, how do you teach someone in Inuktitut (or elsewhere) about the word "the" (or "a")? How do you translate phrases like "the big red tree" into Inuktitut? If you leave out the word "the", how do you conceptualize this translation process? Now, when I read "the big red tree", "*the*" *focuses my mind* on what's about to come, the "main" thing, "big" merges into the focus the feeling of expanse, "red" prepares a hue, and "tree" nails the object into the experience. Now how do I go from that, into Inuktitut, or any other language which differs a bit from English?

The only language I really know/knew was Spanish, but they have the word "el" for the so it's not of much use in trying to imagine. It's almost a word for word translation. Wondering how I can approach translating a sentence with "the" to a language like Inuktitut, and also how I could teach them about the concept.

Comment: Why invent descriptions like "swivel" when there are already standard terms for these things?

Answer (score 3):

Determiners (the standard term for words like "the") have long been a problem for formal semantics, which I think is what you're trying to do here—translate a sentence into some formalized, more-or-less-mathematical representation of its meaning.

"The" broadly means "I'm talking about a specific thing that should be clear based on the context". The usual way this is captured is through a special operator ("iota") that means "the unique entity satisfying all of these conditions". So "the cat" translates to ιx.cat(x), "the unique entity (out of the set of entities that could be referred to in this conversation) that is a cat".

This broadly works, but how do you decide what the set of entities that could be referred to in this conversation is? Many semanticists just handwave this as a matter of pragmatics. I'm not aware of any theories that actually formalize what it takes for something to be "in context", since in practice that's a very broad and complicated issue that's hard to pin down mathematically.

Comment: Definite descriptions involve presuppositions, which are definitely pragmatic and not logical. Russell's iota notation never really caught on, I think partly for this reason; it's clearly handwaving and "captures" nothing. Here's [some other presupposition triggers](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf) from Levinson.

Comment: @jlawler I admit all of my formal semantics knowledge comes from classes rather than real life, but I did always find the iota definition lacking. I'm not too surprised to hear that it hasn't caught on in the real world.

Comment: I'm not sure I would call logic, or any mathematics, "the real world". Mathematicians are very real, but they don't always live in the same world.